# Incorrect transaction charges on flow blockchain testnet

Tags: onflow-cadence

While making transactions using gosdk through cadence code I am getting transaction charges as 0.00010000 while in their documentation it is mentioned Transaction Fee: 0.000001 FLOW
https://docs.onflow.org/flow-token/concepts/
Can somebody please help

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is updated now. The correct fee is 10 µF. (0.00001)